# Can't select DataRow from DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, datarow

I'm trying to prevent inserting duplicated data into MS Access table like below,

MS Access table(Record) with Columns: Situation, Check_Item, and starts with no data in the table.
DataTable from DataSet is filled with the query `"SELECT * FROM Record WHERE Situation = 'A'"`.

Then I try to do this process,

```
DataRow = DataTable.Select("Check_Item = '"+InputTextBox.Text"'");
If (DataRow.Length == 0)
{
  Use OleDbCommand to insert InputTextBox.Text string to Check_Item of Record table.
}
```

Result:

First time key in(e.g. 123456), because there is no data in the table, so 123456 is inserted into Record table. 
But at the second time key in 123456, then it still be inserted into Record table.
What happened in this process??

Comment: Did you update `DataTable` with newly added row, before adding next one?

Comment: yeap...about 30 mins ago I just found that I forgot to update the DataTable...
still thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `DataTable` variable has name `table`, and that you created it and linked it correctly to your MS Access database then:

```
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("Check_Item = '"+InputTextBox.Text"'"); //Selects all rows where the condition is met.
If (rows.Length == 0)
{
   //No row met the condition so create a new one and add it to the table.
   DataRow newRow = table.NewRow(); //Creates a new row with the same schema (columns) as the table.
   newRow["Check_Item"] = InputTextBox.Text; //Assigns the value.
   table.Rows.Add(newRow); //Adds the new row to the row collection of the table.
   table.AcceptChanges(); //Commits and persist the changes done to the table.
}
```

Be sure to check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.newrow?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataTable_NewRow) and also the official docs for [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

Comment: Thank you for your replying, I just found that I forgot to update the DataTable haha...I'll take this flow to do error check, thanks.